# How to automatically create an IIS website via script

Tags: powershell, azure, iis, dns

We have a MVC5 C# website that allows customers to buy domain names.
After purchase we then want the website to be automatically created in IIS so that any calls to it (say it's called www.test.com) will show a new templated website.

What would be the best approach for this? would it be best to script in for powershell?

Does anyone know the script that would be needed for this in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You could either create the site uing `c#` or `PowerShell`, its your choice.

For PowerShell, use the [WebAdministration module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee790599%28v=technet.10%29) and the `New-Website`cmdlet. For Azure Website, use [Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview).

Answer (score 0):

To create automatically an Azure website you can use PowerShell or [Azure Management Librairies](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) in C#.

Here is a script to create an Azure Website with Powershell :

```
$rgName = 'example-RG';
$location = 'West Europe';
$servicePlanName = 'example-SP';
$siteName = 'exampleWebsite Name';

Login-AzureRmAccount

#Create the resource Group
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rgName -Location $location

#Create the service plan
New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -  Name $servicePlanName -Tier Free

#Create the web app
New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -Name $siteName -AppServicePlan $servicePlanName
```